# How to prevent php timeout, to run loop? Without manipulating max_execution_time?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a folder with documents that needs to be processed by a php script. Say there are 1000 documents in the folder, each will be deleted after processing.

How can I run or rerun a php script from the browser without hitting the server max_execution_time without manipulating the max_execution_time itself and without using cronjobs?

I thought about some solutions:

-having 2 php scripts that run the same while loop and stop itself after 25 seconds and activate the other script to take over the job. And this back and forward until the folder is empty.

-Using ajax/javascript to stop executing the script and reactivate it again.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: run the script in the background from the cli, no time limits there

Comment: using time() differences in php script

Comment: Be warned with redirecting, lots of redirects will often be halted by modern browsers.

Comment: @coder and why don't you use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` ?

Answer (score 3):

I use the ajax/javascript successfully. 
You can keep the number of items processed in $_SESSION. I run batch that can work for more than one hour with no problem.

Comment: Does this work with ignore_user_abort(TRUE); so you can leave the page while processing? Can you help me a bit more, how does your script looks like, does it stop and rerun the same php?

Comment: You could add ignore_user_abort(TRUE) with the script. Basically, a first script allows the client to set-up the task. It send a forms to the client to upload a csv file with thousands of rows. When the client post the form, it counts the number of rows and store information on $_SESSION. The client is redirected to a progress bar page. The page do the ajax call in the background. At each call, the script process 100 rows, store how many rows it has processed and return the percentage of completion to the client to update the progress bar. The next request process the next 100 rows ...